# Which is efficient (cache/memory) in writting a function handling a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a question: suppose I have a numpy 1D array Arr, whose length is N. Now I want to manipulate it. The demo is:

```
import numpy as np

N = 100 
Arr = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.float64)

def func_1(Arr):
    Arr_out = Arr + 1.0

    return Arr_out

def func_2(Arr, N):
    # resembling allocating memory
    Arr_out = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.float64)
    Arr_out = Arr + 1.0

    return Arr_out
```

As you can see, there are two functions to manipulating Arr and returning Arr_out. The difference is that in func_2, I first specify the shape of Arr_out. Is this necessary in terms of efficiency concerning cache/memory? Thanks.

Comment: `Arr_out = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.float64)` is completely pointless, you assign *another object to the variable `Array_out`* in the next line, `Arr_out = Arr + 1.0`. The array created by `np.zeros(N, dtype=np.float64)` is discarded. So not only is it not necessary, it is pointless and needlessly inefficient, and confusing to any reader who will wonder why you are doing that.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean that 'Arr_out = Arr + 1.0' will create a new array not using the memory address from 'Arr_out = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.float64)'?

Comment: `Arr + 1.0` creates a new array. I suggest you read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html I suspect you have a fundamental misunderstanding about what variables are in Python, perhaps you are coming from C/C++. *Variables* aren't an address, they are simply names that can be bound and reboudn to any object. *Objects* have addresses. EDIT: I see maybe it's actually Fortran. Suffice it to say, Fortran and Python are totally different languages in many fundamental respects, best to forget what you know and learn python on it's own terms. I would start by reading the link in this comment

Comment: Another, fairly good article if you are coming from that sort of language to Python: http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/

Comment: You can use `np.add(Arr, 1, out=Arr_out)` to put the result of the addition into an already existing `Arr_out` array.  But I wouldn't create `Arr_out` just for this purpose.  The code for `np.cross` is an example of this usage.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for introducing np.cross to me.